# What do I do to prevent my website freezing after some time

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, web, freeze

I've got a website (http://liverssreader.com/) which is quite JavaScript (jQuery) heavy. There are several scheduled background tasks (refresh of feeds) and animations. After an hour or so the browser tab freezes. Are there any obvious things to check to prevent this from happening (emptying animation queues or similar)? I was thinking of doing a complete website refresh after an hour or so, but that's not very user friendly. Any suggestions are welcome :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the Google Chrome browser, open the developer tools, and go to the Profiles tab.  The tools available there might be able to help you track down what is bogging down your page.  (I'm assuming that the freezing is happening on the client side, not the server side - this wasn't entirely clear from the question.)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I like this... never used the profile section before... won't mark it as answer just yet :) Do you know any good resources on explaining the Profiles section by any chance? I'll google some of course, just if you've got any favorites. thanks again!

Comment: No favorite resources of my own, and your Google is as good as mine.